# Adding same views with different parameters from perspective, eclipse framework

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I currently have 5 ViewPart-s which show similar data but in various ways, using jit visualisation. I want to combine them into one class with parameters.
From my IPerspectiveFactory I'm adding these selectively, e.g. just first 2 views.

My question is, how can I instantiate the same view with different parameters(like parametrized constructor). Later I'll be adding them with secondary id..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass parameters to a view.

I would suggest using a base class containing most of the common view code and then a class derived from that for each of the different views.

Comment: I already have that situation, but I thought I could do it via parameters...

Thank you for your time! :)